# Firebase: How to get only one single document from collections? Prevent amount of reads from database

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can we get a single document from a collection, and at the same time prevent the db go through all documents to find the specific one?

I recently checked my "Usage" of the firestore-database and I'm the only one have access to it. My first invoice said "400k+" read/write (while reloading data etc). But now, still, today, it says 1.2k+ reads when I get only 9 lines of values from a document-field.

This is how I get the data (button-click):

```
final DocumentReference docRefData = db.collection(-ref-).document(-ref-);
    docRefData.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            pDialogLoading.dismissWithAnimation();

            Log.d(TAG,"-ref-: completed...");

            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                // If task is successful, We can get the result!
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                if(document.exists()){

                    Log.d(TAG, "-ref-: DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());

                    Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();

                    if (map != null) {

                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {

                            -ref-.add(entry.getValue().toString());
                        }

                        System.out.println("-ref-: "+-ref-.size());

                        Collections.sort(-ref-);

                        Log.d(TAG,"-ref- result: "+-ref-);

                        showStationInfo(-ref-.get(-ref-).substring(1)
                                ,-ref-.get(-ref-).substring(1)
                                ,-ref-.get(-ref-).substring(1)
                                ,-ref-.get(-ref-).substring(1)
                                ,-ref-.get(-ref-).substring(1)
                                ,-ref-.get(-ref-).substring(1)
                                ,-ref-.get(-ref-).substring(1)
                                ,-ref-.get(-ref-).substring(1)
                                ,-ref-.get(-ref-).substring(1));

                        Log.d(TAG, "-ref-: Last -> " + -ref-.toString());
                    }


                }else{

                    Log.d(TAG,"No such document");
                }
            }

        }
    })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    Log.d(TAG,"-ref-: Get document failed: "+e.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Any idea on what is causing the high read by this code? As I understand the dB reads from top to bottom in order to find the value I wanna get. And that, ofc, is pretty stupid. But maybe there isn't any other way to get it?

Thanks

Comment: You are already doing that. You are getting the a single document from the following location `root -> -ref- -> -ref-`. Why do you say that you are going through all documents to find the specific one?

Comment: I went through your code, and whatever you're doing seems to be correct. You're getting data from one single document db -> -ref- -> -ref-. You don't need to add limit as I said in first comment. There's something else that's eating your read/writes.

Comment: @AlexMamo Right, that's what I thought. Until I checked "usage" and saw 1.2k+ reads. That's nothing I've done myself since I loaded in the data to fbDb about 2 weeks ago. What I expected to see were about 10-50 reads. But only for today, it says 1.2k+ reads. I don't know why it says that.

Comment: @VedprakashWagh Right, do you have any ideas on what it could be? Because I had pretty much a heartattack when I saw the invoice specifications showing 400k+ last month? It seems to me that it eats lot of reads when getting data, and this is the only method for getting data.

Comment: Since in your code I can see that you are getting only a single document, the problem may come from the orther parts of your code. Do you have any other queries in your code?

Comment: That's a lot of reads. I have 3000+ daily active users and I have only 11K reads in last 7 days. Your this code seems correct to me as you're fetching only one document. How many users do you have?

Comment: This is what it says "current quota period" 
Reads
1.2K / 50,000, 7 june - 8 june. And when I check last 7 days it says 333, I don't know if it's some sort of a bug. My Invoice said following: App Engine Cloud Firestore Read Ops May 1 - May 24 190855 Counts 0.39, it's sick!